# Adding different colour to alternater bars

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Here is my sample data which I am working on:-

```
                   Day1-G    Day1-W    Day2-G    Day2-W    Day3-G    Day3-W
Deviation of 1        61        54        61        59        69        68
Deviation of 2        75        68        76        71        75        75
Deviation of 3        85        80        86        80        78        83
Deviation of 4        88        86        92        83        88        85
```

What I am trying to do is to plot bar chart for each row (deviation 1 to 4) in separate plot to show the performance of `G` and `W` for each day. I would like to have different colour for `G` and `W` so as to easily distinguish the content. The following sample code results the semi desired plot:-

```
_winter = os.path.join(data_path, 'winter.xls')
xl = pd.ExcelFile(_winter)
df_win_max_temp = xl.parse("Min Temp")
row = df_win_min_temp.iloc[0]
dev_1 = row.plot(kind='bar', title="Winter Minimum Temperature ", stacked=True, figsize=(16, 9), legend=True, fontsize=14, grid=True,
                     color=['g', 'b'])
fig = dev_1.get_figure()
fig.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=.25)
plt.show()
```

Above code results in producing this plot:

[image]

The issue I am facing is that the colour values not changing as per the `color=` statement. How can I plot the different colour values for each bar. I would like to have just green and blue alternately.

Comment: Your code works fine when I run it, alternating blue and green stacked bar plots.  Are you sure your sample data is representative of the actual data?

Comment: Well I get a warning `warnings.warn(("'colors' is being deprecated. Please use 'color'"`

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot about that.  But that's not the issue, see my updated comment above.

Comment: I have posted exact set of data I am trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add colors as a string using the single character shortcuts.

```
dev_1 = row.plot(kind='bar', title="Winter Minimum Temperature ", stacked=True, figsize=(16, 9), legend=True, fontsize=14, grid=True,
                     color='gb')
fig = dev_1.get_figure()
fig.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=.25)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]